# Set Simple recovery model before shrinking SharePoint database

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server, database

I read several articles recommending switching to **Simple** recovery model before shrinking dbs.
[Here](https://nhutcmos.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/reduce-size-of-sharepoint-log-database/), [here](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/shrink-sharepoint-config-db-log-file/) and [here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3019714/shrinking-an-already-ginormous-sharepoint-database-transaction-log.html).

Please explain me - Why it is needed.

I also read [the white paper about Maintenance of SharePoint Databases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc262731(v=office.14)#shrinking-a-database-by-using-transact-sql-commands) - there is nothing about switching to Simple model.

Our SP dbs configured to Full recovery model. DBA tried to shrink db on dev without switching to Simple recovery model. Shrink was done smoothly without any issues.

P.S.
I know that shrinking of SP databases is not recommended, but sometimes it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn’t be needed.  Switching to the simple recovery model breaks the backup chain of transaction logs which may be worse than having the shrink recorded in them.

Are you referring to the data files or the transaction logs?  Shrinking the TLs is trickier as it heavily depends on how many pages are free (have been backed up) at the end of the log file.

Comment: Greg, thank you for the answer. I am about shrinking transactions log file.

Comment: Yeah, they’re a lot trickier.  There’s plenty of pages on the net describing why shrinking the TL doesn’t free up as much space as you think.

Comment: We tried to shrink db log files on dev env and it was free a big amount of space

Comment: It all “depends”.  If you’re in the full recovery model, you can’t shrink the TL at all unless it’s been backed up.